# How can I set decimal places in JavaFX spinner?

Tags: javafx, spinner

I want to make JavaFX spinner with 3 decimal places as a double value, so I just made `Spinner` like this:

```
Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner<Double>();
SpinnerValueFactory<Double> valueFactory =
    new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0, 512, 51.197, 1);
spinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
spinner.setEditable(true);
```

I just made spinner with initial value as 51.197, but when I run this code, initial value is 51.2; and when I edit spinner as 52.666, I can't use this value. I think that the decimal place is problem.
I want to use value form as `###.###`. How can I handle JavaFX `Spinner` decimal place?

Comment: Try setting the [`converter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.html#converterProperty) to a [`NumberStringConverter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/util/converter/NumberStringConverter.html) with the appropriate pattern.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you. I did what i want using StringConverter :)

Comment: The documentation says that the default double factory is ##. ##. So you'll need to add your own as slaw mentioned. I think you also need the constructor to be (0, 512,  51.197, 0.001)

Comment: @HyungjinJeon if you solved your question you should post it as an answer and accept it so if others find this post they know how to fix their problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem with [`StringConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html).

```
StringConverter<Double> doubleConverter = new StringConverter<Double>() {
private final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.###");
@Override
public String toString(Double object) {
    if (object == null) {return "";}
    return df.format(object);}
@Override
public Double fromString(String string) {
    try {
        if (string == null) {return null;}
        string = string.trim();
        if (string.length() < 1) {return null;}     
        return df.parse(string).doubleValue();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {throw new RuntimeException(ex);}
    }
};

Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner<Double>();
SpinnerValueFactory<Double> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0, 512, 51.197, 1);
spinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
spinner.setEditable(true);

SpinnerValueFactory.setConverter(doubleConverter);
```

Comment: A related example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55427306/230513).

Comment: Note you could use `new NumberStringConverter("###.###")` instead of implementing your own.

Comment: @Slaw might be being stupid, but this throws a compilation error for me, `incompatible types: javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter cannot be converted to javafx.util.StringConverter<java.lang.Double>`. Does this work with `SpinnerValueFactory<Double>`?

Comment: @Dan Ah, you're right. Sometimes I really dislike how they designed the generics in JavaFX. You might be able to create a workaround with `ListSpinnerValueFactory` but it honestly may be easier to just do what HyungjinJeon does in their answer and ignore my comment.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the quick response :) Shame you can't use it like that